# Validity of sphere-packing argument for converse channel coding theorem

Tags: information-theory, packing-problem

The well-known capacity formula for additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN) channel is given by
\begin{align}
C=\frac{1}{2}\log_2(1+{\sf SNR}) \text{ [bits/channel use]}
\end{align}
where ${\sf SNR}=P/N$ is the signal-to-noise ratio.
In other words, there exists some code enabling reliable communication with a rate less than $\frac{1}{2}\log_2(1+{\sf SNR})$, and there is no such code enabling reliable communication with a rate larger than  $\frac{1}{2}\log_2(1+{\sf SNR})$.

This can be directly verified from Shannon's channel coding theorem with mutual information computation. But, for information theory newbies, the so-called ["sphere-packing argument"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise#Channel_capacity_and_sphere_packing) is welcomed due to its intuitiveness. As shown in the above Wikipedia link, the converse part (an upper bound of achievable rates) posits that $n$-dimensional balls whose centers are codewords and radii are $\sqrt{nN}$ should not be overlapped to rid of the error.

What I'm wondering is the validity of this argument. To the best of my knowledge, the sphere-packing density is upper-bounded by $2^{-0.599n}$. When applying the sphere-packing argument again with this bound,
\begin{align}
\text{(density)}=\frac{M\times \sqrt{nN}^n}{\sqrt{n(P+N)}^n}\leq2^{-0.599n},
\end{align}
which boils down to
\begin{align}
R=\frac{\log_2 M}{n}\leq \frac{1}{2}\log_2(1+{\sf SNR})-0.599.
\end{align}

This clearly contradicts with the Shannon theory. I guess that error can be asymptotically zero even when approving slight overlapping. My questions are:

1. Is my thought -- sphere-packing argument contains logical flaw -- reasonable?
2. If so, how can we modify the argument?
3. And is my guess true?

Comment: The sphere packing argument I believe is only approximate. The received words can fall out of the claimed spheres with non-zero probability.

Comment: @VinayakSuresh I don't think that point is approximate. The probability you mentioned vanishes as the dimensionality goes infinity by means of the law of large numbers.

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-451-principles-of-digital-communication-ii-spring-2005/video-lectures/chap_3.pdf Please check this for a more detailed mathematical argument